# How to access a local ActiveX control written in C#

Tags: .net, activex

I want to load an html file in a browser locally (not through a web server) that runs some javascript that loads and executes an ActiveX control written in C#. The control may or may not contain .NET forms. Can this be done?

Comment: Only if the user is running IE.

Comment: Or Firefox with the ActiveX plugin.

Comment: @Eric: no, that plugin won't let you use windows forms.  This is IE-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you're using a browser that supports ActiveX and it's configured to allow ActiveX to run in the local security zone.

If you open a local XML file with IE, by default you get the message:

> To help protect your security,
>   Internet Explorer has restricted this
>   webpage from running scripts or
>   ActiveX controls that could access
>   your computer.

This is an example of a browser running active content as a result of loading a local file.

Have you tried this?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I get the above message, but the control just shows up as a place holder. Is there a security setting in .NET that may be causing issues?

Comment: There's nothing I'm aware of that should prevent a trivial ActiveX control from displaying.  If your ActiveX control is trying to access secured resources, it's doing it within the context of the browser.  Can you try a trivial ActiveX control that does nothing but show a simple UI so you know it worked?

Comment: I downloaded and tried running a sample from 'http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/exposingdotnetcontrols.aspx?msg=152695'. It works under tstcon32, but doesn't show up in the browser at all. They have things locked down pretty tight here, I am going to try it at home later.

Comment: I get around locked down environments by running things in a Virtual PC.  If you can set one up, or get the IT folks to do that for you, might make it easier for you to try different security settings.

Comment: Got it to work at home with a couple of changes, but the same code doesn't run here, so I suspect it is a security setting somewhere.